# What are the spaces over spacetime points in which a field takes its values? Is it always the same?

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory

When it comes to the [fibrations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration) encountered in field theories of physics, are the fibers over the base space always the same?

Answer (score 1):

In gauge theory, the connection (the potential in the electromagnetic case) is defined over a fiber bundle with fibers in some suitable Lie Group. Yang Mills theories are theories with Lie Group $SU(N)$, while in electromagnetism the group is $U(1)$. So for all these theories, the fiber in the fiber bundle is a Lie Group.

The case where I know there is some fiber degeneracy and some notion of fibration might be useful is when dealing with singularities in GR. The b-boundary approach to singularities for example add fibers in the frame bundle that might be completely degenerate.

EDIT:
Christoph's comment.

> slight correction: while the typical fiber of the principal bundle is the Lie group, the connection form (aka gauge field) as well its curvature form (aka field strength) take their values in the Lie algebra

Comment: What is the b-boundary approach? What objects are added to the frame bundle? And at those new fibers the direct sum of frame bundle and that new object then?

Comment: The b-boundary approach is a way to systematically add boundaries to spacetimes with singularities. The basic idea is to build a riemaniann metric in the frame bundle using the metric in the base. However the completion in the frame bundle might not be a fiber bundle. Some fibers might be degenerate. The fiber might be a point or a subgroup of the linear group. It depends on the characteristic of the singularity. A detail explanation is in Hawking & ellis "The Large Structure of Spacetime" Chapter 8.

Comment: Also something you may find related to your question is the problem of Gribov Ambiguity. I am afraid I don't know much about it, but as far as I understand in general when you try to construct the orbit space, which is the quotient of gauge connections (sections of the fiber bundle I mentioned in my answer) over the gauge transformations ( the automorphism of the fiber bundle that live invariant the base manifold),  it will be a bundle but not a fiber bundle. This is related to topological obstructions of the theory.

Comment: slight correction: while the typical fiber of the principal bundle is the Lie group, the connection form (aka gauge field) as well its curvature form (aka field strength) take their values in the Lie algebra

Comment: That's right. I added your commentto the answer. Also as differential forms in the base space, the connection is a 1-form and the curvature tensor is a 2-form.